# Seleniums Gecko driver crashes when going to new web pages

Tags: c#, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I am using the new Gecko Driver to test in Firefox. When I change the url it often fails. I have a test that goes to 10 different pages to perform a very basic health check. The pages always load when using Firefox manually (not Gecko/Selenium), but when using the Gecko driver it fails on the GoToUrl().

It's not consistent which of the ten pages it fails on, but it is always consistently failing on one of the ten. When it fails Firefox closes and an error message pops up asking if I want to submit the details to Mozilla.

Am I doing something wrong, or is there some restriction with the Gecko driver that I am unaware of? The Chrome and internet explorer drivers handle the exact same test just fine.

```
var service = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService(DriverPathOnSystem);
var driver = new FirefoxDriver(service);

driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
```

**EDIT**

- Selenium.Support v3.4.0 (nuget)
- Selenium.WebDriver v3.4.0 (nuget)
- Firefox 51.0.1 (32-bit) but also using the most recent version on the
  build machine and it has the same failure there
- Gecko 0.16.0

Comment: what versions are you using?  Firefox version? Geckodriver version? Selenium version?  **please edit your answer to include these**

Comment: @sircapsalot done!

Comment: Can you please paste the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon further research I discovered I was actually using WebDriver v3.2.0.

I updated WebDriver to v3.4.0, 
updated FireFox to 53.0.0,
updated GeckoDriver to 0.16.1
cleaned the solution and rebuilt and it worked.